# regex issue while parsing .pdf file using CAM::PDF

Tags: perl, pdf

Unmatched [ in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/ <-- HERE / at ./pdf_parse.pl line 37.

Actually I'm parsing .pdf file word by word [in order to make a dictionary out of it]
line 37:-

```
if(grep(!/$word/,@line_rd)){
}
```

Well actual word where parser script stops working is in different font [in side the pdf which I'm parsing], is that the culprit here ?
Whether CAM::PDF recognizes words in different fonts ?  What care should i do, in order to stop this !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote `$word` in the regular expression if it can contain special chars (like `[` or even `.`). Try with:

```
if (grep(!/\Q$word\E/, @line_rd)) {
  ...
}
```

If you want to make a dictionary of all the words, use a hash:

```
my %allwords;
...
  # each time you have a new word incoming from the parser:
  $allwords{$word}++;
```

At the end, the `%allwords` hash will contain the distinct words as keys, and the word count as values. You could e.g. print it using:

```
map {
 print "Word $_: count: ", $allwords{$_}, "\n";
} (sort keys %allwords);
```

Comment: yet the words which are different fonts are  not displayed properly...it displaying like "^@W^@\^@S^@H^@G" !

Comment: Do i need to use any encoding style or i need to convert all the words in to plain-text ?

Comment: you'll need to post a bit more code to show how you are getting `$word` and `@line_rd`, that doesn't look like anything.

Comment: Ultimately CAM::PDF didn't extract all pdf's contents...it can extract only plain-text [I'm not talking about images etc, however non-plain text like usually c++ code or path variables like /bin/perl....which are usually in some different font than plain text].

Comment: @mandy: fonts and encoding are two completely different things. if parts of your PDF are encoded in some way, then those parts need to be decoded appropriately before you can use them in regexs. CAM::PDF has a bunch of parser functions, without knowing what you are doing exactly, and what your PDFs contain, it's pretty hard to help you.

Comment: Consider a .pdf document of man_page of a command where plain text & code snippets are present in different font, here I'm able to parse normal plain text, howevr not the code snippet ! hope it'll clear my issue to you ! thanks.

Comment: @mandy: no it doesn't clear up anything. Why are you putting a piece of data that contains "^@W^@\^@S^@H^@G" in a regex?

Comment: Ok...I'll explain my problem ! e.g. I'm parsing below line from pdf file, I'm interested in each word [separated by space]. "Create the /etc/vx/ file to list files". Here i'm able to parse words like- Create,the, file,to,list...however not bale to parse /etc/vx/. AT the same time you can find the font of vx & other words are different [I'm not bale to parse stan-alone word vx also...even if it's present in some other part of pdf].

Comment: Since I'm making a dictionary out of all words, for not allowing duplicate entry i'm checking it in previous version...here  "^@W^@\^@S^@H^@G" is nothing but "vx" word.

Comment: @mandy: see my update about building a dictionary of unique words. You don't need grep or a regexp for that.

Comment: @mandy: can't help you with that without having a sample of the real data to see the actual encoding.

Comment: Find below paragraph :-"Making the caching settings persistent across mounts make the settings persistent by creating the /etc/vx/odmadm file and listing the caching settings in the file
To make the caching setting persistent across mounts
the following example of the /etc/vx/odmadm file, if you mount the
/dev/vx/dsk/rootdg/vol1 device at /mnt1, odmadm turns off caching for
/mnt1/oradata/file1:
setcachemap data/read_data_header=cache
setcachemap all/datapump=cache,readahead
device /dev/vx/dsk/rootdg/vol1" here I'm not bale to extract words from code snippet !

Comment: @mandy: this does not help. You are getting data in some encoding which is not plain ascii in your script. We would need to see that **raw data** to be able to try and guess what encoding it is and decode it.

Comment: well, how to find out encoding style inside pdf ?

Comment: @mandy: that is exactly what I am telling you: we can't if we don't have an example of the actual, raw binary data to guess the encoding. Fonts and styles have nothing to do with it.

Comment: ok Mat ! thanks for your help...i'll attempt it one more time.

Comment: "ext4" is written in Identity-H encoding, does CAM::PDF supports this encoding style ? I think not...then how to decode this encoding, in order to parse or read the pdf file.